# How do I replace lines between two patterns with a single line in sed?

Tags: sed, awk

This is my input file:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

I want to turn the file into

```
one
two
three
NEW LINE
eight
nine
ten
```

with sed. That is, I want to replace the lines from `/four/` (including) to `/seven/` (including) with the single line `NEW LINE`.

I can do that with

```
sed '/four/aNEW LINE
/four/,/seven/d' file.txt
```

But I am wondering if there is a simpler way, notably one without having to repeat a pattern (as I needed to with `/four/`).

**Edit** As per *fedorquis* comment-question, this can also be in awk (although for "academic" purposes I'd be interested in sed solutions.)

**Edit 2** Unfortunately, the input file suggests that there is a logical order of words in the input file (*one* followed by *two* followed by *three* etc). In my "real world" problem, this is not the case, however. I have no idea how many lines the file has, nor what is preceeded or followed by the lines *four* and *seven*. The onl thing I know is that there is a line *four* which is (not necessarily immediately) followed by a line *seven*. I am sorry for not stating this clearly when I asked the question, especially because *fedorqui* has put so much effort in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed $'/^four/{:a;N;/^seven/McNEWLINE\nba}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl is pretty concise, and you don't need to repeat any keywords:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/four.*seven/NEW_LINE/s'
```

Comment: Note the "s" flag on the "s///" operator -- that allows "." to match a newline character.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, you can delete from line `four` to `seven` and append after `seven`. Which is in fact what you posted in your question :)

```
$ sed -e '/seven/a \NEW LINE' -e '/four/,/seven/d' file
one
two
three
NEW LINE
eight
nine
ten
```

---

With `awk` you can do:

```
$ awk '/four/ {f=1} !f; /seven/ {print "NEW LINE"; f=0}' file
one
two
three
NEW LINE
eight
nine
ten
```

What it does is to keep updating the flag `f` that stops the printing.

- When "four" is found, the flag is activated.
- When "seven" is found, the flag is deactivated, printing also the `NEW LINE`.

Comment: Come on! You are cheating in your sed! You repeat the 3, and you aren't really matching any patterns, just relying on the line numbers!!!! :-)

Comment: I take the bait :) Improved, @MarkSetchell thanks for pushing so that I learnt how to do it :)

Comment: The "problem" with your solution is that it is pure coincidence that *eight* follows *seven*. In my "real world" problem, I only know that there is a line "four" and "seven", and that "seven" is after "four". But I don't know how many lines are between, nor what is immediatly followed by "seven".

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger the funny thing is that after trying and trying I came up with a solution... which is the one you comment in your question :) `sed -e '/seven/a \NEW LINE' -e '/four/,/seven/d' file`. It was nice to play with it, though, as well as seeing other answers, both very smart! Just updating to delete the number references in botk `sed` and `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you do in `sed`:

```
$ sed ':a;N;s/four.*seven/NEW LINE/;ba' file
one
two
three
NEW LINE
eight
nine
ten
```

Logic is pretty much similar to [Glenn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719238/970195) answer. Slurp the entire file in to one long line separated by newlines and substitute everything from four to seven and replace it with NEW LINE.