# replace all lines between 2 matching words

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two files;

**in1.txt**:

```
bbb
ccc
ddd
aaa
ccc
bbb
ddd
```

**in2.txt**:

```
sss
```

In `in1.txt`, I want to replace lines from `aaa` to the first occurence of `ddd` with the contents of `in2.txt`.

**Desired output**:

```
bbb
ccc
ddd
sss
```

Comment: Could you give an example of desired output? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, I have in1.txt and in2.txt. in2.txt has string sss, I want to check for 2 matching words in in1.txt i.e(in1.txt has  ccc ddd aaa bbb ccc ddd rrr ddd ttt ddd) something like this. I want to check for the word aaa to immediate occurance of ddd and replace it with in2.txt content. Output should be ccc ddd sss rrr ddd ttt ddd -- all the spaces are separate lines

Comment: Can the start and/or end text contain RE metacharacters (i.e. are you looking for regexp or string matches)? Can the replacement text contain backreference metacharacters? Can the start and/or end text be a subset of some other text contained elsewhere in the file (i.e. are you looking for partial or full word or full line matches)? Can the start/end strings be together on 1 line? Can there be multiple start or end strings on 1 line? If any of that can happen how should it be handled? Really **think** beyond just the most trivial sunny day cases and include those requirements and examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace lines between two patterns with a single line in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718708/how-do-i-replace-lines-between-two-patterns-with-a-single-line-in-sed)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr:

```sh
$ sed -e "/aaa/,/ddd/c\\$(cat in2.txt)" in1.txt
bbb
ccc
ddd
sss
```

In detail:

```sh
$ sed -e '/START/,/FIN/c\REPLACE_WITH' file
```

`/START/,/FIN/` indicates the range of text to replace - beginning with `START` and ending with `FIN`.
The `\c` is used to replace the previous declared lines with `REPLACE_WITH`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, I checked this cmd but if I have multiple lines in in2.txt then it is not taking all the liens in the in1.txt. I am getting the error. Eg : in2.txt is again aaa bbb ccc then it is taking aaa not bbb and ccc. Can you please help me with this? I used the below cmd : sed  -e "/aaa/,/ddd/c\`cat in2.txt)`" in1.txt and the output I got is sed: can't read sss: No such file or directory
sed: can't read sdf: No such file or directory
sed: can't read asd: No such file or directory
sed: can't read fsd: No such file or directory
ddd
bbb
ddd
SSS
eee

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 'x;/x/{x;:a;n;ba};x;/^aaa$/{:b;N;/^ddd$/M!bb;x;s/^/x/;x;r file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

In order to make the replacement once only , set a flag in the hold space and check every time a line is read in, if that flag has been set. If it has, print the remainder of the file using the `n` command and a loop.

If the flag has not been set, on encountering the start delimiter, accumulate the the file up until the end delimiter in the pattern space. Set the once only flag and read in the contents of the second file. Finally delete the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the nice `sed` solutions that have been provided, I have added a `awk` one:

**Input files:**

```
$ more in*.txt
::::::::::::::
in1.txt
::::::::::::::
bbb
ccc
ddd
aaa
ccc
bbb
ddd
::::::::::::::
in2.txt
::::::::::::::
sss
```

**command:**

```
awk -v delim1="aaa" -v delim2="ddd" -v target=in2.txt '{if($0 == delim1){test=1;system("cat "target);next}if(test !=1) print;if($0 == delim2){test=0};}' in1.txt
```

**output:**

```
bbb
ccc
ddd
sss
```

**Code:**

```
{
 if ($0 == delim1) {
  test = 1
  system("cat " target)
  next
 }
 if (test != 1) {
  print $0
 }
 if ($0 == delim2) {
  test = 0
 }
}
```

**Explanations:**

1. `-v delim1="aaa" -v delim2="ddd" -v target=in2.txt` you pass the 2 delimiters to `awk` as parameters as well as the file you want to read from (`in2.txt`)
2. When you reach the first delimiter, your `test` variable is set to `1` and you print the content of `in2.txt`, you jump to next line.
3. if `test` variable is different than `1` you print the line (this means that you have not yet encountered the first delimiter)
4. When you reach the 2nd delimiter you reset `test` to allow the printing of the rest of the file.